# decoding string from jasmin problems

Tags: python, unicode, jasmin-sms

I'm receiving an encoded string from jasmis-sms, the original string is `áéíóú ñaña!`, jasmin does some encoding and gives me:

`����� �a�a!` (in my terminal)

which chardet detects as `charset: windows-1252`
But when trying to decode that with

`Message.decode('windows-1252')`

But that returns

`<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)`

String is coming from jasmin-sms on an interception python script

The script is launched by jasmin-sms on receiving an SMS via smpp, it injects a global variable `routable`, which contains all the SMS's data, the complete code is:

python2

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
import chardet

file=open('/opt/jasmin-scritps/interception/mo-interceptor.log','a')
file.write('===============================================================================\n')
file.write('Start logging...\n')

SMS_to = routable.pdu.params['destination_addr']
SMS_from = routable.pdu.params['source_addr']

SMS_message = routable.pdu.params['short_message']

file.write('To: [%s]\n' % SMS_to )
file.write('From: [%s]\n' % SMS_from )
file.write('ShortMessage: [%s]\n' % SMS_message.encode("hex") )
file.write('data-coding: [%s]\n' % routable.pdu.params['data_coding'] )
file.write('charset: %s\n' % chardet.detect( SMS_message )['encoding'] )
file.write('decoded: [%s]\n' % SMS_message )
file.write('SmppSatus: [%s]\n' % smpp_status )

file.write('Content: [%s]\n' % routable.pdu.params['short_message'] )
```

And I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

And help is really appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post the complete line, that is failing and also show line that opens  the jasmin file and also specify the python version you're using.

Comment: OK you know probably that python2 will be end of life (availability of fixes / updates / security fixes) by January 2020.

Handling of unicode differs between python2 and python3.

If you can I suggest to use python3 if you can't I suggest to look whether you can pip install future, add the line `from io import open` as first line,
change `file=open('/opt/jasmin-scritps/interception/mo-interceptor.log','a')` to `file=open('/opt/jasmin-scritps/interception/mo-interceptor.log','a', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: need a second comment. (not enough characters left)
then replace `file.write('decoded: [%s]\n' % SMS_message )` with
`file.write('decoded: [%s]\n' % SMS_message.decode("cp1522'))`

if you can't use the future library and you want to write code, that might not work with python3, then just try *as only change !!!)


`file.write('decoded: [%s]\n' % SMS_message.decode('cp1252').encode('utf-8') )`

Comment: Thanks @gelonida Thanks! that worked PERFECTLY!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what of my three suggestions did you  follow?
python3?  python2 with future? or python2 only?

Comment: A question to the SO experts.

If a comment resolves an issue. Should it be copied to be a solution?
Does this question have an added value to be searchable with an answer?

Or would it be better to link this question to a similar encoding / decoding question?

Consider also, that this is python2 and such questions might perhaps  be of less and less interest, though some people might still be stuck with python2 for a few years despite it's end of life

Comment: I think you should copy the comment as a answer and possibly ellaborate a bit.